# How can I truncate this PHP statement?

Tags: php, coding-efficiency

I'm trying to program more efficiently by reducing repetition.

```
<?php if (isset($user_school_data[0]) && trim($user_school_data[0] != "")) print($user_school_data[0]) ?>
```

Is there a way I can shorten the statement above?

Comment: [Ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)?

Comment: `trim($user_school_data[0] != "")` has the bracket in the wrong place - I think - `trim($user_school_data[0)] != ""`

Comment: You could always print something - even if empty - `print (trim($user_school_data[0]??''));`

Comment: @user3783243 This should trigger a Notice if the value doesn't exist, because you're not using `empty` directly on it.

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of PHP's [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) (only with PHP7 onwards):

```
<?php if (strlen(trim($user_school_data[0] ?? ''))) print($user_school_data[0]) ?>
```

- `$user_school_data[0] ?? ''` basically means: evaluate to 
  `$user_school_data[0]`, or if it doesn't exist (or is null), replace it with an
  empty string.
- [`strlen`](http://www.php.net/strlen) then checks the length of the trimmed string.

As @Nigel Ren suggested in the comments, you can also omit the condition completely if it just prints the value:

```
print(trim($user_school_data[0] ?? ''));
```

This will only print the value if it exists and its trimmed version is not empty.

Comment: @user3783243 You're right, I'll add it to the answer.